# Reputation over time - as the site grows, this might be the more important measure

Tags: discussion, reputation

As the sites get older, there are more and more users (like myself) who have slowly accumulated small amounts of reputation over the course of years.  We may also have (almost accidentally) answered a simple question that it turns out that a lot of people are looking for the answer for and get a slow trickle of rep from that.

Then there are other users that will have come on and built up a large amount of reputation over a much shorter time by answering a lot, and generally being clever.

Do you think we should have another number displayed by our profile in an answer, something like 'rate of reputation growth'?  As time goes on, absolute reputation amount becomes less of an accurate measure of how 'good' you can expect someone to be.

Comment: What would this "rate of reputation growth" mean for those looking at it? What value would they extract from it in order to rate a question/answer over the existing metrics?

Comment: You can always see how long a member has been registered. For example you've been with us 4 years 7 months and you can see the [reputation graph](http://stackoverflow.com/users/117215/paddy?tab=reputation&sort=graph) so all this sort of already exists

Comment: I know that this all exists, and have browsed through it etc. It's really a bit of an idle thought, but when looking at a couple of answers you get a a rough idea of how much to weight someone's answer when you see the rep built up by the answerer (visible by the answer).  It may be more about making this data more visible at a glance.

Comment: I"m not interested in the metric on the profile page, but rather about having the data on the profile link hover

Comment: What does it actually matter really though, if you took 10 years to build up 10k or 1 year. You've still provided 10ks worth of useful answers and probably know what you're doing (just have more real work to be getting on with)

Comment: So users who get lots of rep quickly are "better" than those who do so over a longer period of time? Or do they perhaps spend an insane amount of time on the site, where others have a life off the site? It's so open for interpretation that I don't really see a use for it, nor a benefit of it.

Comment: Possibly per question might make more sense.  If you've only answered 5 questions, but have a high rep, it's likely that you know what you're talking about.  e.g. Jon Skeet - while he also answers a lot of questions, his responses are generally highly upvoted due to the quality and depth of knowledge they contain.

Comment: Yeah I totally disagree with this. It really doesn't say that a person is better if he's no lifing on this website...

Comment: @Paddy: if your idea was implemented, would you really look at this new data? Will it be interesting for you to see that the user has accumulated reputation in a short time or a long time?

Comment: Rep per post doesn't work either. For example, on SO right now I have roughly 23.05 rep/post(counting questions and answers). Jon Skeet has 22.72 rep/post, so apparently I'm "better" in some way?

Comment: Rep per post would mean punishing people for answering question in less popular tags. Answer upvoted by 50% of tag readers would be able to push someone down, if his other answers are upvoted by only small %, but in a much more popular tag, as the amount of people active in different tags ia dramatically different.

Comment: @Geobits - are you?

Comment: No. 1) He contributes *far* more to the site. 2) He has helped approximately 60x the people I have, going by answer count. 3) He's almost assuredly a better programmer in general. Yet by this measure, I would rank as "better" for SO somehow. Note that the only reason his score is so low is because he hits the rep cap *every day*, and rep/post is a punishment for doing that. If he answers 10-15 questions a day, it's almost guaranteed he won't go much above 20/post.

Comment: In addition, the *easiest* way for someone with decent existing rep to gain rep/post is to *stop contributing*. Every time a new vote comes in on an old question, it would increase rep/post, while answering new questions would *decrease* it.

Comment: Wow. This is really going to hit my points/post on meta...

Comment: @Geobits - had forgotten about the rep cap (haven't really encountered it too much myself :)

Comment: What is the point of measuring how good you can "expect" someone to be? Shouldn't you be judging their answers based on their answers, not some number?

Comment: And who cares about your points on meta? is the discussion valuable? Then consider it an investment. Were you really saving those points for something special? Right now you're +9 on this question. Boo hoo.

Comment: I really need to make the sarcasm clearer.

Answer (score 8):

No, because reputation points have zero relationship to the correctness of someone's answers or quality of their questions.  The purpose of reputation is for the site software to determine what access rights you will get, based on how much you have used the site successfully.

That's why we vote on questions/answers.  It shows how good the question/answer is.  Then this info is what determines the reputation that goes to the user.

You cannot take two answers and say the one from a high rep user is probably better than the answer from a low rep user.  That is putting the cart before the horse.  Judge the answer itself, not the name attached to it.

Comment: And if I wanted to call people out, I could cite many examples of extremely crappy answers from extremely high-rep people.

Answer (score 4):

You can already see who gained the most reputation this week/month/quarter/year by looking at the [users page](https://stackoverflow.com/users).

Answer (score 3):

Because the number of votes a post get is proportional to the number of views, you have to factor out the number of views:

```
confidence score = votes/views * 100;
```

I've floated this idea before, but it's never gotten much traction.